# Add Google sheet with data using Google API v4

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Python. I need to add sheet in spreadsheets using Google API v4. I can create a sheet using batchUpdate with spreadsheet id and addSheet request (it returns shetId and creates empty sheet). But how can I add data in it?

```
data = {'requests': [
    {
        'addSheet':{
            'properties':{'title': 'New sheet'}
        }
    }
]}

res = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=s_id, body=data).execute()
SHEET_ID = res['replies'][0]['addSheet']['properties']['sheetId']
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured out that after creating sheet inside spreadsheet you can access range 'nameofsheet!A1' i.e.

```
service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=s_id, range='New sheet!A1', body=data_i, valueInputOption='RAW').execute()
```

This request will post the data into new created sheet with name 'New sheet'

Answer (score 4):

You can add this code to write data in Google Sheet. In the document - [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values)

> Spreadsheets can have multiple sheets, with each sheet having any number of rows or columns. A cell is a location at the intersection of a particular row and column, and may contain a data value. The Google Sheets API provides the [spreadsheets.values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) collection to enable the simple reading and writing of values.

Writing to a single range

> To write data to a single range, use a [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) request:

```
values = [
    [
        # Cell values ...
    ],
    # Additional rows ...
]
body = {
  'values': values
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_name,
    valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
```

> The body of the update request must be a [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource-valuerange) object, though the only required field is **`values`**. If **`range`** is specified, it must match the range in the URL. In the ValueRange, you can optionally specify its [majorDimension](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#dimension). By default, ROWS is used. If COLUMNS is specified, each inner array is written to a column instead of a row.

Writing multiple ranges

> If you want to write multiple discontinuous ranges, you can use a [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) request:

```
values = [
    [
        # Cell values
    ],
    # Additional rows
]
data = [
    {
        'range': range_name,
        'values': values
    },
    # Additional ranges to update ...
]
body = {
  'valueInputOption': value_input_option,
  'data': data
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

> The body of the batchUpdate request must be a [BatchUpdateValuesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate#request-body) object, which contains a ValueInputOption and a list of [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#resource-valuerange) objects (one for each written range). Each ValueRange object specifies its own **`range`**, **`majorDimension`**, and the data to input.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try a 'more intuitive' library i wrote for google sheets api v4 , [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets) as i found the default client bit cumbersome.

```
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize()

# Open spreadsheet 
sh = gc.open('my new ssheet')

# create a worksheet    
sh.add_worksheet("new sheet",rows=50,cols=60)

# update data with 2d vector
sh.update_cells('A1:B10', values)

# or skip let it infer range from size of values
sh.update_cells('A1', values)
```